# Wordpress basic plugin backend on running?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have built a basic contact from that has multiple divs, after testing this on my localhost without CMS it seems to work, but when i create a wordpress plugin and call the form via shortcode the post does not show any sign of being filled.

```js
function pagechange(frompage, topage) {
   var page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+frompage);
   if (!page) return false;
   page.style.visibility='hidden';
   page.style.display='none';
   
   page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+topage);
   if (!page) return false;
   page.style.display='block';
   page.style.visibility='visible';

   return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
   <div id="formpage_1" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
   <h1>We would Love to Hear about your Project!</h1>
   <p>Please answer a few questions, this will save time on communication and help you receive an answer quickly.</p>
   <?php if(isset($_POST['cf-submitted'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name-form'];
   echo $name;
      } ?>
   <input class="button1-form" type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(1,2);" />
  </div>
  <div id="formpage_2" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
   <h4>What is your name?</h4>
   <input type="text" name="name-form" />
   <input class="next-btn-form" type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(2,3);" />
  </div>
  <div id="formpage_3" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
   <h4>Hello! Tell us your Company Name?</h4><?php echo $name; ?>
   <input type="text" name="companyname" />
   <input class="next-btn-form" type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(3,4);" />
  </div>
  <div id="formpage_4" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
   <h4>Tell us a bit about your Project?</h4>
   <input type="text" name="project" />
   <input class="next-btn-form" type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(4,5);" />
  </div>
  <div id="formpage_5" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
  <h4>What is your email so we can contact you?</h4>
   <input type="email" name="email" />
   <input class="next-btn-form" type="submit" value="next" onclick="pagechange(5,1);" />
  </div>
```

I just tested it on the jsfiddle, doesnt seem to be working either now, am i missing something here?
Im still learning so i am not the best XD

Alex

Comment: The quotes within the `isset()` function look off.

Comment: I fixed the quotes on isset function but still not receiving any output. Thanks for pointing that out.